# Why boost python calls the copy constructor?

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

Assume a wrapper class is provided

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        std::cout << "hello\n";
    }
    Example(const Example& e)
    {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
        counter++;
    }
    ~Example()
    {
        std::cout << "bye\n";
    }
    Example& count()
    {
        std::cout << "Count: " << counter << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    static int counter;
};
int Example::counter = 0;
```

which is exposed to python using

```
using namespace boost::python;
class_<Example>("Example", init<>())
        .def("count", &Example::count, return_value_policy<copy_non_const_reference>());
```

now if i execute the following python code

```
obj=Example()
obj.count().count()
```

I get

```
hello
Count: 0
copy
Count: 1
copy
bye
```

which means boost python is using the copy constructor.

My questions:

1. Why the copy constructor is called?
2. If I use boost::noncopyable, then the copy constructor is not called. However, in this case I cannot execute my python code as it complains about a to_python converter (see below). Is there way to fix this?

   TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy constructor is called because `return_value_policy<copy_non_const_reference>()` is being set and by [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/python/doc/v2/copy_non_const_reference.html):

> copy_non_const_reference is a model of ResultConverterGenerator which
>   can be used to wrap C++ functions returning a reference-to-non-const
>   type such that the referenced value is copied into a new Python
>   object.

It complains because the return value is required to be copied but at the same time the class is `noncopyable` so the default converter is not found.

To fix this either don't use `return_value_policy<copy_non_const_reference>()` or define your custom `to_python` converter.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I should use boost::python::return_self<>() instead.